# How do I avoid invalidating my CDN cache whenever I add a new blog post to my database?

Tags: django, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, cloudflare

I am using Django REST API as a backend to a blog, with the front end in React hosted separately.

I have the React front end behind Cloudfront, acting as a CDN.

Whenever I want to add a new blog post / add any new record in my DB, I need to invalidate my cache for it to actually appear on the site. I understand why this happens.

I want to know how I can avoid this, and still get the benefits of caching without wiping my whole cache everytime I want to see my new content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers to control how long objects stay in the cache. Settings for Minimum TTL, Default TTL, and Maximum TTL also affect cache duration, but here's an overview of how headers can affect cache duration:

- The Cache-Control `max-age` directive lets you specify how long (in seconds) that you want an object to remain in the cache before CloudFront gets the object again from the origin server. The minimum expiration time CloudFront supports is 0 seconds. The maximum value is 100 years. Specify the value in the following format:

`Cache-Control: max-age=seconds`

For example, the following directive tells CloudFront to keep the associated object in the cache for 3600 seconds (one hour):

`Cache-Control: max-age=3600`

- If you want objects to stay in CloudFront edge caches for a different duration than they stay in browser caches, you can use the `Cache-Control max-age` and `Cache-Control s-maxage` directives together. For more information, see [Specifying the amount of time that CloudFront caches objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist).

[More in Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)